# Relocate wordpress website address via localhost using openServer

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I started my website locally using openserver and changed the address of my site through general settings in wordpress settings. I couldn't get my site up and running after that. I can't access cPanel either, maybe because I'm running on localhost. How can I solve this problem?

I reverted the changes and clicked save site back to old name but it didn't work. I completely deleted OpenServer and the folder where the site is located from the computer and reinstalled it, but when I started it, nothing changed.